# migration issue, django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: lightspeed.inventoryimagehistory has no field named 'imageID'

Tags: python-3.x, django, migration, database-migration, djongo

I'm having issues with this Django project, when I try to run migrations got the following message:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: InventoryImageHistory has no field named 'InventoryImageID'
```

this is the class for InventoryImageHistory

```
class InventoryImageHistory(models.Model):
ImageID = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True, null=False, primary_key=True)
history = ListField(DictField())
objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

these are the migration files:

[image: migration files 35 and 40, the last one is the one who fails]

migration file number 40:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='inventoryimagehistory',
            old_name='InventoryImageID',
            new_name='imageID',
        ),
```

De model definition is InventoryImageHistory, but for some reason, it keeps returning an error

Comment: I think there is a typo in the model def. The field name's supposed to be imageID and not ImageID. Can you verify if that's correct?

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 you're right, there was a typo model def, now i got: django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: InventoryImageHistory has no field named 'InventoryImageID'

Comment: Can you post the model schema before the change? Also, looking at the migration file would be useful.

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3, already edited the post, I cant put all the file as Stackovertflow wont allow me, the object definition is class InventoryImageHistory

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting the same thing--FieldDoesNotExist during a RenameField. I mean, it's not in the models... because I'm renaming it. Isn't that the point? I must be missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few minutes after I posted my comment I seem to have fixed it. It was because I had initially put the RenameField in the previous (not yet committed to repo, but already applied) migration, and even though that one had been applied, Django seems to parse all of the dependency migrations logically and decided that the rename had already happened.

Answer (score 0):

This message might have to do with the fact you faked/manipulated some migrations in that app recently.

What I do when this pops up is to:

1. Create another change in that models.py file (i.e.: add an extra field to the model).
2. Run the migration
3. Do the change I wanted to do in the first place that triggered the error and run the migration (hopefully successfully this time)
4. Undo the change I added on 1. and run migrations again.